# Getting powernap's IOMonitor to work with postgresql

Tags: power-management, postgresql, powernap

I have a 12.04 box running postgresql 9.1.8-0ubuntu12.04, which serves a Java webapp (an Atlassian Confluence wiki).  I'm trying to take advantage of powernap's IOMonitor feature.  However, if I uncomment the corresponding line in `/etc/powernap/config`:

```
[IOMonitor]
postgres-io = "postgres"
```

... powernap never allows the box to go to sleep, the logs (with DEBUG=3) show this:

```
Looking for [postgres-io] IOMonitor
Activity found, reset absent time [0/60]
```

One thing I have noticed is that postgres appears to be respawning processes every 2-3 mins (even without any user activity against the wiki); every time this happens, powernap prints:

```
<powernap.monitors.IOMonitor.IOMonitor instance at 0xXXXX> - adding new PID 16783 to list.
```

The PIDs in questions appear to be the ones serving my wiki DB, eg:

```
postgres 16783  1067  0 11:05 ?        00:00:00 postgres: confluence confluence 127.0.0.1(50689) idle
```

I presume this is getting in the way?  Is this an issue with Postgres (is it supposed to respawn processes that often, even w/o activity?).  Any pointer as to how I go about debugging this would be most appreciated (maybe starting with how powernap infers I/O activity - since there are many postgres processes, perhaps I can find a regexp that will target just the right one?).

PS: If I comment out the Postgres IOMonitor, powernap works a treat but then it does suspend the box while the Wiki is being used...

Comment: Pg isn't really designed to totally stop all I/O; things like the autovaccum workers, stats collector and bgwriter tend to keep I/O ticking over lightly. Ideally you'd be able to get your activity monitor to ignore such I/O but unless you can match on and exclude the process names that'll be hard. Can't you just monitor the network I/O sockets for the wiki instead?

Comment: Thx a lot Craig! I suspected smth of the sort was happening.  Powernap does have a `[TCPMonitor]` section for the purpose you suggest; I tried sticking the Wiki's http port in there (8080) but activity doesn't seem to get detected.  I suspect this might be because powernap only samples (using netstat) every so often and the http connections are too transient?

Comment: Actually I can see the http connections showing ESTABLISHED for reasonable length of time using `netstat -a`.  Upon closer inspection, I noticed the connections occur over IPv6 (for obscure reasons), which led me to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/powernap/+bug/1070695)

Comment: That looks like an answer candidate to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per above comments - with thanks to @craig-ringer for putting me on the right track!

1. Postgresql isn't suitable to I/O monitoring to determine whether it's idle
2. Instead, it's better to monitor TCP connections to the front-end app if possible
3. However, be aware of [bug 1070695](https://bugs.launchpad.net/powernap/+bug/1070695) if your connections are established over IPv6.  The bug ticket has a patch which worked a treat for me.